# How to set Isolation levels with java jersey?

Tags: mysql, jersey, isolation-level

I am using Java Jersey https://jersey.java.net/ for a simple project with a MySQL DB. I found how to set the lockmode but I would like to also know how to set the transactions isolation levels. 
I can't find it anywhere !
rXp

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Jersey. You can set the isolation level on your jdbc connection:

```
Connection conn = ...; // get connection from somewhere

conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);
```